# Swift - Why does my SKShapeNode pass through an object, pausing briefly beforehand?

Tags: collision-detection, ios

The code below when run on a device that’s flat on the table shows a red circle (the 'ball') and a line.

When I gently tip the device the circle moves towards the line. When it reaches the line, it stops which is the expected and desired behaviour.

BUT if I keep tipping, the circle moves *through* the line. I’ve been trying for 2 days to work out why grrr I just want the circle to hit the line and **not** go through it.

Any ideas? Anything to do with the line being an 'edge'?

Cheers,
Andy

```
import SpriteKit
import CoreMotion

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {   
    var ball : SKShapeNode!
    var line : SKShapeNode!
    var motionManager = CMMotionManager()
    var destX : CGFloat!
    var destY : CGFloat!
    let ballRadius = CGFloat(20.0)

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: ballRadius)
    ball.fillColor = UIColor.redColor()

    ball.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width/4, y: frame.size.height / 2)
    destX = frame.size.width/4
    destY = frame.size.height / 2
    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ballRadius)
    addChild(ball)

    line = SKShapeNode()
    var lineStart = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width/2, y: 0)
    var lineEnd = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width/2, y: frame.size.height)
    var linePoints = [lineStart, lineEnd]
    var linePos : CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathAddLines(linePos, nil, linePoints, 2)
    line.path = linePos
    line.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    line.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeFromPoint: lineStart, toPoint: lineEnd)
    addChild(line)
}

override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
    moveBall()
}

func moveBall() {       
    motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(
    NSOperationQueue.currentQueue(), withHandler: {
        data, error in
        var currentX = self.ball.position.x
        var currentY = self.ball.position.y
        self.destY = currentY - CGFloat(data.acceleration.x * 100)
        self.destX = currentX + CGFloat(data.acceleration.y * 100)
        }
    )
    ball.position = CGPoint(x: destX, y: destY)
    }
}


import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let skView = self.view as! SKView
    let scene = GameScene(size: CGSizeMake(
    skView.bounds.size.width, skView.bounds.size.height))
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
}
```

EDIT: many thanks to Attackfarm :)

I changed the moveBall() function as follows:

```
func moveBall() {
    motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(
        NSOperationQueue.currentQueue(), withHandler: {
            data, error in
                self.ball.physicsBody!.applyForce(CGVector(dx: -data.acceleration.x*100, 
                        dy: data.acceleration.y*100))
        }
    )
```

which in this proof of concept demonstrates what I needed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not applying a force or a velocity to the ball.  Rather, you're simply changing the position.  If the tilt is small, it doesn't move much, and is thus stopped by the physics simulation.  If the tilt is large, you're setting a position past the edge, thus the physics simulation does not even concern itself with the collision since the ball "teleports".

To solve this, simply apply the tilt as a force acting upon the physics body rather than a change directly to position.

Comment: You're quite welcome  =)